# Tumblr -hd images?

Tags: html, css, tumblr, retina-display

I'm working on a Tumblr theme.

I want my theme to be `@2x` compatible so I the jQuery retina plugin:
https://github.com/tylercraft/jQuery-Retina

You must name your files the same, except that you add a suffix of your choice to the `@2x` one, line `-hd` or `_2x`.

You can make your images available via [Static Tumblr Upload](http://www.tumblr.com/themes/upload_static_file).

The problem is, that Tumblr always generates a custom URL component:
http://static.tumblr.com/user/aRandomCode/blabla.png

Now that random code is what is messing it up.

How should I fix this? I'm assuming that I'm probably not the only one making them in `@2x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a jQuery plugin, you can just specify your new assets with CSS:

```
@media 
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

This will cut down on needing to load an extra plugin. More reading: http://www.brettjankord.com/2012/11/28/cross-browser-retinahigh-resolution-media-queries/

Comment: Thank you! I guess there is no other way